# Which datatype to use to store TimeTaken field in SQLIte?

Tags: c#, sqlite, time

I want to create a field in SQLite DB(using C#) to store time taken(duration) field. The value will be in `hr:min:sec` format, like `'10:10:00'` which means 10 hrs, 10 min and 00 seconds. WHich Data type should I use for this? I know `DateTime` will not be adequate since its used to store date-time.

Comment: You should add C# tag to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `TimeSpan` in C#.  This is meant to represent an elapsed duration of time, which is what you are describing.

In SQLite, you should store an `INTEGER` type so that your data is sortable.  You simply need to decide what granularity you need.

For example, you could store the `TimeSpan.Ticks` if you care about the absolute finest precision possible.  You would need an `INTEGER` of 8 bytes for this.  When loading, you can use either `TimeSpan.FromTicks`, or the constructor `new TimeSpan(ticks)`.

More likely, you will want to store a whole number of seconds, which you can get from `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`.  You could probably use an `INTEGER` of 4 bytes for this.  When loading, you can use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` to recreate the timespan from your integer.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` or `TimeSpan` would be more than adequate, but SQLite doesn't support them.

In SQLite, possible data types are `TEXT`, `INTEGER`, `REAL` and `BLOB` (equivalent to .NET `String`, `Int64`, `Double` and `Byte` array respectively).

All you have to do is manipulate your C# `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` to your preferred SQLite data type.

Comment: SQLite can hadle `DateTime` well, as string, integer or real, depending on the `DateTimeFormat` specified in the connection string. Unfortunatelly, it cannot handle `TimeSpan` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Matt Johnson answer is the most adequate, however, I came out with another approach. In my case, the problem was a little bit different. I had to store reservations for a restaurant, and among others I had these 2 fields:

- DateTime StartDateTime
- TimeSpan Duration

Since you can't store TimeSpan in Sqlite I create a column name EndDateTime, of type DateTime. So Duration is the difference between EndDateTime and StartDateTime, like this:

```
StartDateTime = reader.GetDateTime(5);
Duration = reader.GetDateTime(6).Subtract(StartDateTime);
```